# Disabled Datepicker is validated

Tags: html, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a form class with several inputs. There is a Checkbox, which enables/disables Datepicker input (Datepicker is not required) based on boolean variable (switchDate). Even if the Datepicker is disabled, it will be still validated and causing whole form to have status invalid.
My submit form button condition is: [disabled]="productForm.invalid". Unfortunately this button will be disabled without valid Datepicker field.

My question is: how to validate Datepicker field **only** if it is enabled?

PS **I am newbie to Angular**

- I've tried to change submit button disabled criteria to focus on other fields errors, but this way it will pass any input in Datepicker
- I was trying to find some method to check if the Datepicker field is enabled/disabled inside submit button condition, but no luck here

```
<input type="checkbox"
             name="switcherChk"
             id="switcherChk" 
             checked="true"
             (change)="changeDatepickerVisibility()" />

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
                      [min]="todaysDate"
                      placeholder="Example text"
                      formControlName="userDate"
                      [attr.disabled]="switchDate ? '' : null"
                      required = false
                      >
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
      </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      <mat-error *ngIf="productForm.controls['userDate'].invalid">
          Date should be greater or equal to current date.
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Have you tried using reactive forms? Those will allow you to dynamically add and remove Validators.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this possiblity. I found some tutorial regarding your hint and I will try to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this way (on the Component side):

```
  private changeUserDateValidators(): void{
    var dateControl = this.productForm.get(this.UserDateField);
    if (this.switchDate) {
      dateControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    else {
      dateControl.clearValidators();
    }
    dateControl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can replace Validators.required to your custom validator.